# Redirect after logout Tank Auth CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I've googled, and googled and googled, and I can't find the answer to this question anywhere.

I'm using Tank Auth with CodeIgniter. I have no problems loading up the views for login, register etc.. My issue is, when I make a link for logging out, it logs out fine but then it redirects me to the login page. I want to redirect to my home controller. I can do this after login just fine, but can't for the life of me find where to redirect after logout. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
function logout()
{
    $this->tank_auth->logout();

    // Redirect to home page
    redirect('', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was actually coming back here to remove my question because as soon as I posted it, I figured it out. Only took me 3 hours. I was trying to follow the methods but they dead ended.. lol.